# versioning file metadata in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to version metadata - file description, custom properties via Google Drive API?
AFAIK Drive versions only file-content, right?

I have read the documentation, but this is not explicitly stated anywhere.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisions contain some of the previous metadata as well as previous content. Take a look at `Revision` [1] resource to find out what the API is providing.

[1] https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions#resource

Comment: Thanks Burcu, I did try this, debug resultset, but there is not file description and also file-properties looks like they are not versioned. BY properties I mean: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/properties

Comment: ooouuiii, the properties are not be revisioned with the file and we only revision what's in the resource set. Editing my answer to point that out.

Comment: Ok, so properties and some file attributes (e.g. file title, file description) are not revisioned (just summarizing). Thanks for the clarification